# VZW Galaxy Nexus exhibiting bizarre charging behavior

Tags: battery, charging, samsung-galaxy-nexus

Lately I've noticed some weird behavior with my Galaxy Nexus. I am rooted, but running stock ICS.

Here is what it's doing wrong:

- Phone sometimes will not charge, I must turn it off for it to start charging
- Taking phone off the charger doesn't remove the lightning bolt [charging icon] from the notification bar.
- Phone begins alerting constantly at 14% battery.
- Battery life seems shorter

Is this likely to be an app doing this? I don't want to wipe my phone if possible, so is there a way to track down the cause?

Comment: alerting what at 14%? that the battery is low?

Comment: I've never experienced any of these problems before... I know you don't want to wipe your phone but you might have to consider it.

Comment: The first point sounds like it's drawing more power than the charger is giving it -- make sure you're using a wall charger and not a USB cable from your PC.

Comment: I've had the some of these issues on my Nexus S running the stock 4.0.3 as have other people, I think it's a software issue, there's a few threads on the Google forums about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official bug report here, starting at about post 26, it seems the sentiment is that this is a hardware issue.

I have contacted Verizon and they are shipping me a replacement. I will update the question again if this does not permanently resolve the issue.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23789&q=label%3APriority-Medium&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars